# C#/SQL changing logging - best methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, logging

Not sure if this question is suitable for StackOverflow as it's much more 'general'. Basically, I have a database driven business application made in ASP.NET and C#, which'll be used by around 20 members of a company. A crucial aspect of this is auditing - I need to log on any changes to any of the tables, and have them viewable by senior members of the staff.

My current solution uses SQL triggers, but I need to create something much more robust and user friendly. The database is gigantic, with a lot of tables with relations etc, and the audits currently are very uninformative to the users - telling the staff that x user modified an order to have a customer of ID of 837 is near enough useless - I need to be able to dictate which field is displayed in the audit log.

My idea is to create a class in my code that'll handle all these, and somehow map out what fields to display to the user, and also somehow tell the code which table was modified and which record.

Can anyone offer any general advice on how to do what I want, and whether it's actually possibile? I'm a heavy user of LINQ-to-SQL in my code, so I'm hoping that'll help...

Comment: Auditing should never reside anywhere except the database. You want to audit all changes not just the ones that come from an application. Triggers are a good solution, if your triggers don't have the right data then change them.

Comment: On the other hand triggers are a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using `DoddleAudit` for your needs. It provides automatic auditing of all inserts/updates/deletes for any table in your database with a single line of code, including:

```
What table was modified?
What fields changed?
Who made the change?
When did it occur?
```

You can find it here: http://doddleaudit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar audit requirements for a healthcare application, which used linq-to-sql for data access.

One way to do it centrally in Linq-to-sql is to override `SubmitChanges` in the data context class. Before submitting the changes, call `GetChangeSet()` to get data about the pending changes. Then add change tracking information as appropriate to a relevant log table before calling `base.SubmitChanges()`. In my application I used an xml column to be able to store change data for different tables in a structured manner, without having to create special history tables for each table in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using SQL Server 2008's Change Data Capture feature. It basically captures inserts, updates and deletes on the desired tables, and stores changes made into a separate set of relational tables.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1474/using-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/